# How do I size an NSWindow with auto-layout?

Tags: cocoa, autolayout, nswindow

Been trying out the SwiftUI default project code Xcode makes for macOS-based document projects.  I moved the window creation code from the `NSDocument` subclass to a new `NSWindowController` subclass.  It started like:

```
init() {
    let content = ContentView()
    let windowSize = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Constants.defaultWidth, height: Constants.defaultHeight)
    let window = NSWindow(contentRect: windowSize, styleMask: Constants.windowStyle, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
    window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: content)
    super.init(window: window)

    // Other setup.
    window.center()
    window.delegate = self
}
```

Now I want to try creating the window without specifying its rectangle.  There is an initializer for that, which uses an `NSViewController` for the base:

```
init() {
    let content = ContentView()
    let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: content)
    let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: controller)
    //window.contentMinSize = NSSize(width: Constants.defaultWidth, height: Constants.defaultHeight)
    window.styleMask.formUnion(.fullSizeContentView)
    super.init(window: window)

    // Other setup.
    //window.center()
    window.delegate = self
}
```

The `ContentView` is just Xcode's default one with only a "Hello World!" text block.  It doesn't seem to have an intrinsic size, so window shrinks to nothing.  The `contentMinSize` property that's now commented out didn't fix it.  Then I read the documentation for the initializer closer and decided to try something with auto-layout.

```
init() {
    // Create and size content.
    let content = ContentView()
    let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: content)
    let guide = NSLayoutGuide()
    controller.view.addLayoutGuide(guide)
    guide.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: CGFloat(Constants.defaultWidth)).isActive = true
    guide.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: CGFloat(Constants.defaultHeight)).isActive = true
    controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //controller.view.autoresizesSubviews = false

    let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: controller)
    window.styleMask.formUnion(.fullSizeContentView)
    super.init(window: window)

    // Other setup.
    //window.center()
    window.delegate = self
}
```

But I still got a disappearing window.  (The commented-out change to `autoresizesSubviews` didn't help.)  I then noticed that a window was there, but with a one-pixel width and a height of about two title-bars.  However, when I tried resizing it, the window became visible, jumping to the minimum size needed for the text block.  Once touched, I couldn't shrink the window below what's needed to show the text block.  However, that minimum size is still less than my default width and height, so those settings are being ignored.

So, how do I control the size of a window as `NSWindow.init(contentViewController:)` wants using auto-layout?

(Hmm, as I type out this query, I'm not sure that the settings I made to `guide` are connected to `controller.view`.  Maybe I need to ensure that first.)

Comment: Have you tried leveraging NSHostingView's fittingSize property?

Answer (score 0):

That last suspicion on using `controller.view` instead of a new `NSLayoutGuide` object seems to work.

```
init() {
    // Create and size content.
    let content = ContentView()
    let controller = NSHostingController(rootView: content)
    controller.view.autoresizesSubviews = false
    controller.view.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: CGFloat(Constants.defaultWidth)).isActive = true
    controller.view.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: CGFloat(Constants.defaultHeight)).isActive = true

    let window = NSWindow(contentViewController: controller)
    window.styleMask.formUnion(.fullSizeContentView)
    super.init(window: window)

    window.delegate = self
}
```

But this only adjusts the size; I can't choose where on the screen the window goes.

Answer (score 0):

If the window size isn't dynamic in both directions (like adding the window to a sheet), try adding the [`fixedSized`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/fixedsize(horizontal:vertical:)) view modifier to your SwiftUI view in one or both directions. The view will then maintain the ideal size of its content and the window *should* respect that size on appearance.

I was experiencing similar issues and it seems like whenever I was adding a `NSHostingController` directly as the content of a `NSWindowController`, things relating to intrinsic sizing started getting a little funky. According to the view inspector, the SwiftUI view is actually properly sized, but the hosting controller's NSView itself isn't (which, afaik looks like a bug. I haven't seen this behavior in other usages of NSHostingController or UIHostingController...).

And lastly, while I haven't experimented too much with this, using an intermediate `NSViewController` between the `NSWindowController` and `NSHostingController` seemingly works.